# Change the format of the date to the YYYY-DD-MM in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['c0'] = [ '2019-01-01 06:00:00',  '2019-01-03 06:00:00', '2019-05-03 06:00:00' ]
df['c1'] = [ 0.4452, 0.2064, 0.1416]
```

I want to change the format of the date as "yyyy-dd-mm". The final dataframe which I want is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this conversion:

```
df['c0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c0']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it to datetime type and use the [strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) method to change the date format.

```py
df['c0'] = pd.to_datetime(df['c0']).dt.strftime('%Y-%d-%m')
```